# Android - Why should we use adapter.notifydatasetChanged() method?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing a Notepad app using Recyclerview.

When adding, removing and editing note, I will return a newListnote which was modified to display on UI and call adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged().

```
public static void UpdateUI(List<Entity_NoteItem> newlistNote) {
    /*listNoteToDisplayOnUI = newListNote();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

    adapter = new DisplayUI_CustomIconLabelAdapter(adapter.context, newlistNote);
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

But I realized that if I assigned the listNote which is set as data of the adapter by a another object with another memory address, the method **NotifyDataSetChanged()** will have no effect.
Therefore, I decided to new adapter with new listNote and called myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) and it gets more effect.

And my question is: Why should we use the method Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() while we can completely new Adapter with the changed data and setAdapter again?

Comment: Doing setAdapter again and again may be inefficient. The adapter itself tends to manage data. The notifyDataSetChanged will take care of updating the UI optimally.

Comment: thank for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why should we use the method Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() while we can completely new Adapter with the changed data and setAdapter again???

When you call `setAdapter(...)`, all rows created from scratch. Bu when using `notifyDataSetChanged()`, old rows can be re-used. So if you want performance, you should use `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Also RecyclerView.Adapter has these methods too:

```
notifyItemChanged(int)
notifyItemInserted(int)
notifyItemRemoved(int)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)
```